# RSQL(Rest) to MongoDb query Converter in C# Asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, mongodb, entity-framework, converters

Basically, I have a method GetById in the controller so based on id I filter out the data as you can see.

```
    public async Task<ActionResult<IList<DocDetails>>> GetDocument([FromRoute] int docType, [FromQuery] string rsql) {
         var filter = Builders<GridFSFileInfo>.Filter.Eq("_id", gridfsObjectID);
}
```

I have one more parameter in my method as a string(rsql). basically, my target is based on the RSQL query I want to filter my data. So, is there any NuGet or something is there that converts RSQL to MongoDB query automatically. So, that I can just pass the query to filter and it will give the desired output.

Comment: Can anyone help me out in this case ?

Comment: I hope my question is clear to all ?